# Can I get Saku instead of Bo?

Tags: .hack-gu, .hack-gu-last-recode

When I played *.hack//G.U* on the PS2 it's revealed that

> Saku, Bo's twin sister, is actually a dual personality of Bo. During a cutscene Saku appears like a ghost above Bo and talks to him (I think it was during the final battle against Cubia).

I don't remember if after this point both Saku or Bo could be chosen for the party, or if it was just Bo, but I prefer Saku. So after

> Saku is revealed to not be real

is it possible for me to get Saku added to my party? Can I do this in *.hack//G.U Last Recode*?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what part of the game you're in. During some stretches only one (or neither) will be available, during others (in particular the post-disc content) both will be available (the other goes "busy" once you've picked one, for obvious reasons)